# Trim() the values of all xml elements and attributes in an xml document using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to take xml like this:

```
<Car>
 <Description Model="Ford      ">Blue     </Description>
</Car>
```

into this:

```
<Car>
  <Description Model="Ford">Blue</Description>
</Car>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML, how about something like:

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes())
    {
        attribute.Value = attribute.Value.Trim();
    }
    foreach (var textNode in element.Nodes().OfType<XText>())
    {
        textNode.Value = textNode.Value.Trim();
    }    
}
```

I *think* that should work... I don't believe you need to use `ToList` to avoid disturbing things as you iterate, as you're not changing the structure of the XML document, just the text.

Comment: This doesn't work. If i have <Car> <Description Model= "Ford ">Blue </Description> <Description Model= "Chevy ">Red </Description> </Car> it returns <Car>Blue Red</Car>

Comment: @user1152145: Okay, will fix it.

Comment: @user1152145: Try now. Basically I'm now handling the text nodes separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Don't forget to recurse through your ChildNodes ...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"c:\temp\cars.xml");
    Recurse(doc.ChildNodes);
}
private void Recurse(XmlNodeList nodes)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.InnerText != null)
            node.InnerText = node.InnerText.Trim();

        if (node.Attributes != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute att in node.Attributes)
                att.Value = att.Value.Trim();
        }

        Recurse(node.ChildNodes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using or can't use LINQ to XML then the below worked well for me with XmlDocument

```
TrimXmlText(xmlDocument.ChildNodes);

private void TrimXmlText(XmlNodeList xmlNodeList)
{
    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
    {
        if (xmlNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            xmlNode.InnerText = xmlNode.InnerText?.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            TrimXmlText(xmlNode.ChildNodes);
        }
    }
}
```